# Wordpress: How to add pagination to page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have 6 posts in Wordpress. I'm trying to display last 5 posts on page. Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Posts Template
*/
?>
//header...
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => 5, 'post_type' => 'post')); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();   ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
//footer
```

Pagination shows me that there is 4 pages, but like I said I have only 6 posts, so how it is possible? Also Pagination seems to not work correctly, doesn't matter on what page I am, it shows always last 5 posts.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `paged` parameter to your query. You can also have a [read of the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) on the topic, there are some examples. Oh, and it's probably more forward-looking to use `posts_per_page` instead of `showposts`.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'paged' => $paged
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to functions.php

```
function posts_nav_link( $query_object,  $show_previous_posts_link = false, $show_next_posts_link = false ) {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $query_object->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $query_object->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() &&  $show_previous_posts_link)
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() && $show_next_posts_link )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

And use **posts_nav_link($the_query)**:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Posts Template
*/
?>
//header...
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => 5, 'post_type' => 'post')); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();   ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php posts_nav_link($the_query); ?>
//footer
```